# Spawn system not working correctly

Tags: unity, c#, scripting

I try to spawn one or two obstacle at the same time given the position rightpos, midpos, and leftpos but i keep getting the spawn position to only rightpos and midpos.

```
     void Start () { 
     rightpos = new Vector2(2f,6f);
     midpos = new Vector2 (0f,6f);
     leftpos = new Vector2 (-2f, 6f);
 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
     if (spawn_activate == true) {
         number_of_spawn = Random.Range (1, 2);
         spawn_activate = false;
     }
     if (number_of_spawn > 0) {
         spawnposition = Random.Range (0, 2);
         if (spawnposition == 0) {
             Instantiate(obstacle,rightpos,Quaternion.identity);
         }
         if(spawnposition == 1) {
             Instantiate(obstacle,midpos,Quaternion.identity);
         }
         if(spawnposition == 2) {
             Instantiate(obstacle,leftpos,Quaternion.identity);
         }
         number_of_spawn -= 1;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html

```
Returns a random integer number between min [inclusive] and max [exclusive] (Read Only).  
Note that max is exclusive, so using Random.Range( 0, 10 ) will return values between 0 and 9.
```

You should try

```
 void Update () {
     if (spawn_activate == true) {
         number_of_spawn = Random.Range (1, 3);
         spawn_activate = false;
     }
     if (number_of_spawn > 0) {
         spawnposition = Random.Range (0, 3);
         if (spawnposition == 0) {
             Instantiate(obstacle,rightpos,Quaternion.identity);
         }
         if(spawnposition == 1) {
             Instantiate(obstacle,midpos,Quaternion.identity);
         }
         if(spawnposition == 2) {
             Instantiate(obstacle,leftpos,Quaternion.identity);
         }
         number_of_spawn -= 1;
     }
 }
```